# How to get row index?

Tags: php, sql

I have a database table:

```
ID  name
15  name1
27  name2
39  name3
```

I need to assign to those rows indexes, like: name1 should have index 0, name2 - index 1, name3 - index 2:

```
ID  name  index
15  name1 0
27  name2 1
39  name3 2
```

I'm trying to do it with cycle:

```
$sub = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT t.* FROM $wpdb->terms AS t, $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt WHERE tt.parent = $termID AND tt.term_id = t.term_id ");           
    $i=-1;
    foreach ($sub as $key) {
    $i++;
    $number[$i]=$i;
}
```

The result of this cycle is:

```
$number[0]=0;
$number[1]=1;
$number[2]=2;
```

Now, I have, for example a row, which `ID` is 27. How should I get a index of this row? (should be 1)

Comment: Why do you want a row index, and why should it be in the database?

Comment: In a RDBMS, a table is a **set** of rows, not an ordered collection. Therefore wanting an immutable row order could lead to surprises afterwards. If you want a natural order use an autoincrement primary key.

Answer (score 2):

You can use foreach as:

```
foreach ($sub as $key => $value) {
}
```

Where $key is the index you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use wordpress myself but I would suggest you try the following to see whats going on:

```
$sub = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT t.* FROM $wpdb->terms AS t, $wpdb->term_taxonomy AS tt WHERE tt.parent = $termID AND tt.term_id = t.term_id ");           
$i=-1;
foreach ($sub as $key) {
print_r($key);
}
```

This will print out the data you are getting back from the query so you can then decide what to do with it. If you are still stuck post the results back here..

Answer (score 1):

Your question seemingly isn't related to SQL.  As in SQL if you already have the `id` *(27)* then you would use that, and not the index value.

So, I assume, you're looking to find the appropriate row in PHP when supplied with an `id` value, possibly by a user.  So, your question is `how to find a record in an unordered array`.

- You can loop through all records until you get a match
- You can create an ordered set matching id to index (such as a binary tree)
- You can create a hash table matching id to index

The faster the search, the more memory it will use.  Which end of the spectrum to choose is dependant on your needs and constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Try that

```
SET @rowId :=0;
SELECT @rowId := @rowId + 1 as rowid , fieldName from tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need row index, store it in database. There is a special flag when you set up your MySQL db structure for auto-incrementing. There is no way to get row index in database, because there is no row indexes, all data you are seeing in database viewer is just result of searching with no parameters. If you REALLY need it, you can just get all data in table and manually get its row id as ign said. (Use foreach key and value)